# Optimization with Maximum in the Objective

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

For vectors, $\beta, c \in \mathbb{R}^d$, $e, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and matrix $B \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times n}$, I am trying to solve the following problem.

\begin{equation*}
\min _{\beta \geq 0} \max_{y_{1}, y_{2}}\Bigg\{\max\left\{e^{\top} y_{1},-e^{\top} y_{1}, e^{\top} y_{2},-e^{\top} y_{2}\right\}+\beta^{\top}\left(c-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{j=1}^{2} B y_{j}\right)\Bigg\}
\end{equation*}

I am not sure how to combine the terms inside the maximum operator with the y terms outside the maximum and reformulate this as a single $\min$ problem. Would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0):

Define
$$
t = \max_{y_{1}, y_{2}}\left\{e^{\top} y_{1},-e^{\top} y_{1}, e^{\top} y_{2},-e^{\top} y_{2}\right\}
$$
This will allow you to rewrite the original optimization problem as
\begin{align}
\min _{\beta \geq 0,y_1,y_2} &~~t ~+~\beta^{\top}\left(c-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{j=1}^{2} B y_{j}\right) \\ \text{s.t.}~~~& e^Ty_i \leq t~,~ -e^Ty_i \leq t ~~\forall i\in\{1,2\}
\end{align}
In terms of your optimization variables $(\beta,y_1,y_2,t)$, this is a quadratic optimization problem with linear constraints. You should be able to rewrite this optimization in the standard form of a quadratic program (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming#:%7E:text=Quadratic%20programming%20(QP)%20is%20the,linear%20constraints%20on%20the%20variables.)) as
\begin{align}
\min_{x} ~~&x^TQx + r^Tx \\
\text{s.t} &~~ Ax \leq b
\end{align}
You will notice that $Q$ is a function of $B$ and couple of other matrices. If you are in luck due to the specific nature of your problem, $Q$ might be positive sem-definite which in turn makes it a convex problem. Otherwise, in general, this is NP-hard.

Comment: The max is over two terms. You used the epigraph just for one term. Also, if $y_2 = 0$, then it is pretty much two linear programs. Not sure about the added complexity with one additional $y_2$ term.

Comment: @Kumar sorry, didn't follow your comment. I see all terms accounted for in the constraints. What fault do you see?

Comment: Max is over $y_1, y_2$, so the second term in the min objective should also get to the constraints. I just edited the expression to make it clear.

Comment: got it! That makes it far more complicated to me. Can you see if results like this are applicable to your case

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax_theorem